# How to upload a file to Node-RED

Tags: node-red

I'm sending a file using the POST form-data request in Postman to Node-RED httpinmultipart node. The payload is empty, return code is 200. How can I access the file in Node-RED?

[{"id":"b2d82b11.654a7","type":"function","z":"f51b5839.7cab1","name":"get fileName","func":"var fields = msg.req.fields;\nmsg.fields = Object.keys(fields);\nvar myFile = fields[\"myFile\"][0];\nmsg.localFilename = myFile.path\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":470,"y":440,"wires":[["65e0bf3a.4b1c8"]]},{"id":"d943250b.95bce8","type":"httpInMultipart","z":"f51b5839.7cab1","name":"","url":"/localpost","method":"post","fields":"[{ \"name\": \"myFile\"}]","swaggerDoc":"","x":230,"y":300,"wires":[["fda8ade.ee538d","b2d82b11.654a7","eb7487d4.9a487"]]},{"id":"fda8ade.ee538d","type":"debug","z":"f51b5839.7cab1","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"false","x":650,"y":300,"wires":[]},{"id":"65e0bf3a.4b1c8","type":"debug","z":"f51b5839.7cab1","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"false","x":680,"y":440,"wires":[]},{"id":"eb7487d4.9a487","type":"http response","z":"f51b5839.7cab1","name":"","statusCode":"","headers":{},"x":670,"y":220,"wires":[]}]

Answer (score 1):

From the README.md and the info sidebar for the [node-red-contrib-http-multipart](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-http-multipart)

> **Usage**
>
> Once installed, a new http-multipart node will be available in
>   your node-red nodes panel. Drag the node onto the flow sheet and use
>   as you would the other http-in node. Output of the node will be a
>   message which contains the files in a msg.req.files object.
>
> To retrieve the file object, you can add a function node to the out
>   port of the node that reads the msg.req.files object.

The uploaded files can be found in `msg.req.files`

Comment: that results in "TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object". I added my flow, maybe I  missed something.